# Getting cannot focus element error for sendKeys function in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Trying to send any data to "from text field" on below link.
https://flights.msn.com/en-in/flight-search

Code is below:

```
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

        WebElement dropdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@href='/en-in/weather'])[1]"));
        dropdown.click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@href='/en-in/travel'])[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[@href='https://flights.msn.com/en-in/flight-search']")).click();
        //WebElement from=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[@class='place-selector js-place-selector'])[1]")));
        WebElement from=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='search']/div[1]/div[3]/div")));
        //js.executeScript ("document.getElementById('from').focus();");
        //from.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //from.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
        from.sendKeys("Delhi");
        from.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Getting  error:

`Error:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element`

Comment: Unless you are leaving comments in your code for explanation or readability, it will be helpful to others if you remove excess code and use consistent formatting! Good luck with your question and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send the word `Delhi` to `a` element then wait until the list appear next click the `li` contain it.

```
WebElement origin = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.js-originplace a"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(origin).click().sendKeys("Delhi");
actions.build().perform();

WebElement from = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul//li[contains(., 'Delhi')]")));
from.click()
```

Comment: it did not work . I am still getting the same error. My requirement is send data on the text field.

Comment: you cannot send any data, it have to select predefined data in dropdown, try wait until `.elementToBeClickable` before `.sendKeys("Delhi");`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not enter proper xpath for from variable, you have forgot to enter index on last div i have shown below let see it helps if this not work then please print or paste all console error or information

```
 WebElement from=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='search']/div[1]/div[3]/div")));

WebElement from=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='search']/div[1]/div[3]/div[index_no]")));
```

I think might be because of elementToBeClickable will you just change and let me know change it by presenceOfElement let see if its work or not

Comment: Akshay , this xpath i have copied from chrome itself and it is highlighting the same text field.